Global $post value outside the loop
On a category archive page, in a filter called from a block outside a loop, I noticed that the get_post function with a null first parameter returns the first loop's post.
Is it supposed to return such a value ? I would have imagined that the global $post variable should have a value only in a loop or on a post page.

Can you add your code snippet here please

Yes, this is how it is supposed to work. The global $post variable is set quite early in the page load, at the wp hook. As you can see from the hook order, this is before the loop starts.
Basically the $post object exists independent from its actual content in the database, which you retrieve during the loop. It's specifically meant to be accessible all the time during page generation.

What value is it supposed to have if it doesn't get its content from the database ?
In my case it seems to still have a peek into the loop to retrieve its first item.

It's a bit like Schrödinger's cat: it doesn't have a value until you open it. The loop is the normal way to open, but you can access it anywhere on the page. get_post will give you the first post of the query and get_posts all of them.

So, it is related to the database content

No, not really. If you approach a website, WordPress first looks at the url. This translates into a query (a post, page, category archive, and so on). That's where the global $post variable is created. Next there are filters that may change the query (for instance amount of posts on a specific category archive page). Only when all this is done the query is actually executed and content is derived from the database.

I'm sorry, I'm confused. What do you mean not really ? And what value is it supposed to have other than null (or false, or anything that can be tested as not initialized) or a database record ?
Of course a variable has no content before it exists. But my question is about that variable value in a block template but before the loop happens.

The $post object is an abstract thing. It points to content, but is it not itself the content. So it can exist without accessing the database. Just like a road sign that says "Paris, 50 km" assures you that Paris exists and tells you where to find it, without itself being Paris. The road sign $post is there form the beginning of the page load, but you will only find Paris when you follow it by using get_post or some other command anywhere in your template.

And when it exists without accessing the database, what value does it have ?

Your are asking your first question again. The $post object is a pointer to database content. The pointer IS the value of the object.

Yes I know and it hasn't been answered. There is no such things as pointer in php … and even so : what would be the value pointed by the pointer ?
